# Magento 2 Stock update API Postman error (Consumer is not authorized to access %resources)

Tags: magento2, rest-api, stock, postman, swagger

I am trying to update the product quantity using postman. But i am getting the following errors

> {
> "message": "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources",
> "parameters": {
> "resources": "Magento_CatalogInventory::cataloginventory"
> } }

Please see the following screenshots

[image]

[image]

**I am missing something ?**

I have seen this documentation https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1/catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1UpdateStockItemBySkuPut

But when I put Pre request I am getting following errors. Please help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use bearer token for this case.

1. Go to System >> Extensions >> Integration , create New Integration and make sure provide privilege Magento_CatalogInventory in tab API - Resource Access.
   After creating integration successfully, you copy "access token" in "Integration Details" Section.
   [image]
2. Paste "access token" into header "Authorization" in postman or type Authorization Bearer token in Header directly
   [image]